# How to specify the path in command line arguments for a property while executing java class

Tags: java, classpath

I need to execute a java application with some command line arguments. The argument is a filepath, which is part of its `resources` folder. Without specifying the wholepath, how to specify it in the commandline.

I am using intellj and executing Main class with VM options

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=xyztruststore
```

`xyztruststore` is placed under `resources` folder.

When I give the full path under the project `xyztruststore` is working.

But how to set the path under `classpath`.

something like `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=classpath:/xyztruststore`

Comment: If file is already in classpath the something like this `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=xyztruststore` should work

Comment: Or: `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/xyztruststore` when accessed like `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xyztruststore")`. (And of course it should not be accessed as File.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But Both tried, not working.

Comment: According to [the JSSE guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.htm#GUID-7932AB21-2FED-402E-A806-3088402BAEA6), the javax.net.ssl.trustStore property always points to a file, not a URL, so there is no way to provide a relative file name that’s guaranteed to be readable, since your program has no control over the current directory.

Comment: But if I gave the file path, it is picking up the trust store and loading to the application.